# how to connect Remix IDE version 1.3.4 to Metamask

Tags: remix, metamask

I'm a newbie to solidity
i'm watching this amazing tutorial on youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org (2:04:15)

and I'm trying to connect Remix IDE version 1.3.4 to Metamask.
in this tutorial and in other places i have searched the way to connect is by choosing "Injected web 3" as the environment in Remix, but in the current version of Remix, this environment is missing.

what alternative do I have with the current Remix version?

Answer (score 1):

You must first set up a MetaMask account. I hope that portion was covered in that video. Pick the **Injected Provider** in the Environment.

[image]

One pop-up window will appear from Remix IDE. Choose the **relevant account** in the MetaMask.

[image]

Then MetaMask account and Remix smart contract were connected together. Feel free to ask for more information if you need it.

Comment: thank you for the reply :)
i followed your steps:

opened metamask,
chose "injected provider.

and there was no popup to continue with.
maybe do you have more ideas ?

Comment: Have you enabled MetaMask extension in your browser?

Comment: yes i enabled metamask in my chrome, I also used it and added testnet funds to the wallet

Answer (score 0):

The `environment` selection option is still there:

[image]

It's the first dropdown of the `Deploy & run transactions` menu.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue like

> No injected provider found. Make sure your provider (e.g. MetaMask) is
> active and running (when recently activated you may have to reload the
> page)

. But Metamask is turn on (only in  Chrome, current Version 108.0.5359.125 (Official Build) (64-bit))

Comment: This isn't a valid answer. If you have the same problem you can vote it, try existing answers, create a bounty, or follow the question for new answers.